# Rails: migrating from sprocket to webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

hi I'm having difficulty migrating my app from rails 5 using sprockets to rails 6 using webpacker. I am using global variables as seen in my code but I've read rails 6 with webpacker does not like this.

root.html.erb

```
<% if logged_in? %>
  <script id="bootstrap-current-user" type="text/javascript"> 
    window.currentUser = <%= render("api/v1/users/user.json.jbuilder", user:current_user).html_safe %>
  </script>
<% end %>
```

I'm wondering what solutions you have implemented to be more compatible with webpacker. Thank you

Comment: Webpacker only cares about files in the assets folder, that's javascript inside a .erb view, webpacker is not involved there. You could have a problem if you try to call a JS function in your view that is part of your JS assets, but in your case you are just setting a window object's variable so you'll have no problem.

Comment: I wrote an article about this migration some time ago when I migrated some apps at work, maybe it helps your transition https://www.fastruby.io/blog/rails/webpack/from-sprockets-to-webpacker.html